# How do I make new rows for the missing time value and fill its data from the row above in pandas?

Tags: pandas

| Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-11-01 | 10:21:00 | 123 |
| 2012-11-01 | 10:22:00 | 57 |
| 2012-11-01 | 10:23:00 | 398 |
| 2012-11-01 | 10:25:00 | 2 |

My date and time were initially in text format and have been converted to a date and time format as shown below.

```
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
data['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'], format='%H:%M').dt.time
```

I need the new filled-out rows for the missing time values and all the needed dates are going to be there. Thank you.

I tried combining the date and time and using ffill but it gives me a lot of repeated rows and I not sure why it does that.